# RDP session is slow

Tags: rdp, remote-connection, remote-client

So I am connecting to my work computer from home and the Remote Desktop Connection app is annoyingly slow.

I pinged my work pc from my computer and it returned at a reasonable time of 50ms~ with 0 loss. I then attempted to ping my home IP from the RDP session and it timed out every time. Not sure if this might help anyone come to a conclusion but hopefully it does. Note I am also using it in conjunction with **Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client** if that helps at all. *Work is Windows 7* and *Home is Windows 8*

I attempted switching off my home pc's firewall but that did nothing.

Any assistance would be great, surely a setting in the RDP file might make it run a little smoother.

I'll edit this post with further attempts at fixes below

Comment: Depends on your bandwidth more than ping response time.  One thing I found greatly improves RDP in my experience is to set the host computers background to solid color black.

Comment: I'm not seeing the programming connection here...

Comment: @JoeC didn't work for me :( but good tip anyway the image i had as my desktop was longer to load thats certain.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Did three things and now RDP is running screaming fast:

1. Change RDP settings:

[image]

2. Run the RDP session and connect to the remote machine
3. Find **mstcsc.exe** in the Task Manager and and set priority to **Realtime**

[image]

Comment: Changing the size of 'Display Configuration' to something smaller also has a huge impact. Not the most practical but much more responsive.

Comment: This solution gave a noticeable difference when using xrdp with KDE plasma! +1

Answer (score 6):

I installed Ubuntu server XRDP. Went through Windows and terribly slowed down. I solved this problem. In the /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini file, change crypt_level=high to crypt_level=None

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? Are you remoting into a Ubuntu server from a Windows computer?

Comment: Yes. I logged in remotely into a Ubuntu server from a Windows computer. By default, the Ubuntu server XRDP encrypts traffic.

Comment: Thank you @Kairat Koibagarov , I don't have permissions to edit this `xrdp.ini` file and I'm afraid to `sudo chmod` in these files that I'm not familiar with. I'll check with IT.

Comment: Since we've left Windows-land, I'll chime in on "xfreerdp" ... I've solved slow connection issues with the "/network:broadband", "/network:broadband-low", and "/network:modem"  options.

Answer (score 5):

Our remote chain is Citrix then RDP, target machine is Win 10.
I solved this issue by changing the mouse pointer scheme to None and disabling the pointer shadow.

[image: mouse pointer setting]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10. Go to Display Settings >> Scale and Layout >> Set the custom scale to 120 [you may need to experiment, try 110 - 150]

After that log in to your Remote Desktop, it should adjust the resolution and scaling factors.

It gave me a faster experience. If you need more then follow the answer of Mr. B